# Why does Zend Framework Validate fail for MimeType, when calling isValid()

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate

This has stumped me for the last few hours.

```
            // Using just straight up FINFO detects the mime type
            $oFileInfo = new finfo( FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE );
            $sMimeType = $oFileInfo -> file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'] );
            // $sMimeType == 'application/pdf';

            // Using Zend File Transfer... detects the mime type
            $upload         = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();                
            $upload->addValidator('MimeType', true, array('application/pdf'));
            // $upload->getMimetype('myfile') == 'application/pdf'

            // But when I try to validate it throws an exception
            $upload->isValid('myfile');
            // Throws 
            // [fileMimeTypeFalse] => File 'myawesomefile.pdf' has a false mimetype of 'application/octet-stream'
```

The code was working fine under Apache, PHP 5.2 (Zend Server), but now it's under Nginx, PHP-FPM, PHP 5.3. I'd love to use the *isValid()* method to validate my uploaded file, but the mime type is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: it depends on the server, linux servers usually works, if you use XAMPP or WAMP they usually have something in the config that is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uploaded file mimetypes are never too reliable...

I usually check file extension as a sad attempt, and if at all possible, try actually checking the contents of the file.

If it's an image, you can run getimagesize(), if it's a PDF, you can create a validator to call Zend_Pdf::load($filename) and check for errors.  Sadly, even the 'Image' validator suffered the same problem for me.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping I wouldn't have to abandon using the validator for file uploads, but if I can't get a reliable mime type out of it, maybe I'll abandon it.

Comment: NP - FYI you can still create a custom validator to do it and attach it to your uploader.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the file extension is not correct when you upload or validate the file, because application/octet-stream appears when you use .* as an extension.

Check the ***file*** function in your ***finfo*** class.

```
//$oFileInfo -> file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'] );
```

Comment: The file I am using to test is a regular old PDF with extension and all. Besides, what I'm trying to figure out is that both FINFO and Zend Framework can see the mime type, but when I use the isValid function to validate, it thinks the file is *application/octet-stream*